# Snake game - how to calculate the next apple position

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random

I'm implementing a Snake game in javascript for fun, I have successfully implemented the snake, its movements and the *snake-growth* thing as it eats an apple.

To calculate the apple position I'm currently following these steps:

1. create a new apple object
2. create random coordinates (X and Y, between game-container boundaries) for the apple
3. check if the coordinates of the apple are equal to one of the snake-blocks coordinates
4. if step #3 is TRUE, recalculate the position of the apple, else draw the apple in the game-container

Unfortunately I found out that this algorithm is very weak.. let's say I have a 10 x 10 game container, the red square is the apple, the green square is my snake head (initial game state)

[image]

as the game progresses the snake eats more and more apples, increasing its length and leaving less and less empty cells to place an apple

[image]

Now suppose that the snake reaches a length equals to 99 while eating an apple. This means that there's **only one** square left to place the next apple. My algorithm (this is the worst case obviously) could take forever in order to randomize the correct value, as it discards any randomized position that it's already taken by the snake's head or tail, not caring at all to randomize the new position in a range of "empty cells" only but instead randomizing on the whole 10 x 10 game canvas.

How should I proceed to solve my busillis? Can you give me any advice on a good algorithm that I can use?

Thank you

Comment: The easiest solution I can think now is to make a list of free coordinates and choose randomly from them?

Comment: @kabanen: In fact that's the best solution :-)

Comment: I think this is not optimal as I have to refresh this list every time the snake moves, removing the occupied cells (I have to scan the list in order to find the cell) and adding the freed ones. Am I wrong?

Comment: Do you add apples on every step? If not, then you can calculate free coordinates only if needed.

Comment: No, you need to do it just when placing a new apple. @kabanen, why don't you write it as an answer?

Comment: @Shomz, well I did it now. I just didn't know, that it's the best solution.

Comment: Even if it wasn't the best solution, it's still a good answer, and you should always feel free to add those. :)

Comment: I had a 10x20 field and just did the random thing. It works without problems for that size, even with only 1 pixel left. But yes, in theory it could take forever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said in comments, the easiest solution I can think is to make a list of free coordinates and then just choose randomly from them.
And you can calculate free coordinates only if needed(when you need to add an apple).

Comment: You could also use your regular approach (random coordinates) until the length of the snake does not exceed certain threshold (e.g.: `length <= 50` for the 10x10 grid), and later switch to the more refined method.

Comment: It doesn't matter much for this small case of a Snake game, but from a Data Structures perspective, it's better to use a Set data structure instead of a list. You will have to do an add operation and a remove operation each time the snake moves, but they will both be O(1) or O(log n), and then when you need a new apple location, the computation will be as simple as randomly picking 1 element from the pre-computed set.